# type mismatch RDD recursive method call in apache spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, recursion, type-mismatch

I am trying to adapt the recursive method (along with the example) proposed in  [Recursive method call in Apache Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35464374/recursive-method-call-in-apache-spark/35494102#35494102?newreg=81dafbc7cfc34a538c01ffd27118a608) . However, I get the following type mismatch error when i call the method RecursiveParentLookup.findUltimateParent():

```
error: type mismatch;
found   : org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Person]
required: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Person]
```

```
val result = RecursiveParentLookup.findUltimateParent(input).collect()
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: @user8371915 Thanks for the answer. My issue is definitevely the duplicate of that one, however no useful answer is provided in that one (I might be wrong though)

Comment: That's the only answer that can be given for this issue unfortunately. It's more scala REPL related than spark